# Dividing a 24-digit binary number to 3 equal parts

Tags: python, binary, integer, decimal, ascii

I'd like to know how can I divide a 24-digit binary number which is taken from user in python to 3 parts and then put different conditions on each of these 3 parts.

```
e.g: input => 111100011110110100100100
```

divide the input to 3 equal parts (each part should have 8 digits): `11110001 | 11101101 | 00100100`
for the first part I want to turn the 8-digit bin num to an int num (no sign + -)
for the second part I want to turn the 8-digit bin num to an int num (with sign + -)
for the third part I want to take an ASCII output from the number in the 3rd part
So the output for the example above will be:

```
241
-109
$
```

I tried to make a list out of the input taken from the user and then get access to index for each divided part but I don't know what I should do to have access to the exact 8-digits part of that input

```
  binaryNum = input()
    if len(binaryNum) < 24:
        print("error")
    binaryList = list(binaryNum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to do it:

[image: image of working code]

My script saves the value as a list and as a string, b/c idk what you wanted the end value to be

- Basically it takes the number
- Splits it into 8bit parts (in a list)
- Converts the first one to denary
- Second one to denary using only the last 7bits
- and makes it negative/positive as per first bit
- Converts the third to denary then to the ASCII char
- Returns this as either a list of a string

Hope this helps!

```
binaryInput = input('Input your binary number: ')

binaryList = [] #blank list
for i in range(0, 24, 8): #every 8th number
    binaryList.append(binaryInput[i:i+8]) #add the number and the next 7 numbers

returnList = [] #blank list

returnList.append(int(binaryList[0], 2)) #convert from base2 to base10

if binaryList[1][0] == '1': #if first char is a 1 (ie negative)
    returnList.append(-abs(int(binaryList[1][1:], 2))) #make denary out of last 7 chars then make it negative
elif binaryList[1][0] == '0':
    returnList.append(int(binaryList[1][1:], 2)) #just convert last 7 chars to denary

returnList.append(chr(int(binaryList[2], 2))) #convert base2 to base10 then base10 to char

for byte in returnList:
    print(byte) #prints each item separably

#returnString = '' #blank string
#for byte in returnList: #for each byte
    #returnString += str(byte) + ' ' #convert it to a string and add a space buffer to end
#print(returnString) #prints as a string
```

[GitHub link to file](https://github.com/Cornelius-Figgle/other/blob/558c9475ee665e4af4d4267039021f03e9d6210f/_stack/binary.pyy)

Comment: Thank you I'll surely use it. It was a big help

Comment: Happy to help, let me know if you have problems! (also I fixed the link)

Comment: Also I haven't tested with numbers other than the ones in your question but I think it should work fine with all numbers xd

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it. How can I get the outputs in **3 different rows**. Shall I use \n in the print section? so that I can have each answer in a row?

Comment: will amend code now! EDIT: now prints each `byte` inside a for-loop, so edit the output there however you need

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not enable others to use Stack Overflow as a code-writing service - instead, only attempt to answer questions that are well posed. This one is clearly far too broad for the format; it is a request to write custom code to complete a task, not a question about a specific problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I know the question was not well asked but idk why you are telling me off for that when I was trying to be helpful. Idm that the question was not asked properly, I was happy to help and I believe that I have suitably explained my answer, and it was a fun task to solve. So whilst their question probably has not massively improved their understanding, it has improved mine and I believe that they should be able to now adapt the code to fit their needs. So kindly, go away, this question was answered 14 days ago and your input would be better directed at OP when they first posted

Comment: "but idk why you are telling me off for that when I was trying to be helpful." Because this is **not a discussion forum**, and the kind of helpfulness you are trying to provide here is contrary to the intended working of the site. Please feel free to ask on Meta if you have any further questions.

Comment: okay thanks for your points, will keep in mind in the future ツ